# NFS3 permissions issue for only some system users

Tags: linux, permissions, virtual-machine, nfs, proxmox

My nfs share is mounted in an ubuntu 22 VM, root, ubuntu and a test user I created can all read/write. However the plex user created by the plex install cannot read or write. When I `sudo su plex` and try to read the contents I get 'Stale file handle':

```
plex@plex:/home/ubuntu$ ls -la /mnt/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root     4096 Jan 18 05:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root   root     4096 Jan 18 05:13 ..
drwxr-sr-x  5 ubuntu testuser 4096 Sep 25 07:07 Share
plex@plex:/home/ubuntu$ ls -la /mnt/Share/
ls: cannot open directory '/mnt/Share/': Stale file handle
```

nfs share settings:

```
/srv/pool/Share     192.168.2.0/24(fsid=1,insecure,rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/srv/pool/Backup    192.168.2.0/24(fsid=2,insecure,rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/srv/pool/General   192.168.2.0/24(fsid=3,insecure,rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

Any tips on how to fix this or further debugging steps would be much appreciated!

Comment: what's the NFS server running? This might be a compatibility problem, or your idmapping just isn't right

Comment: nfs server is running Debian bookworm. uid 1000 is Debian user on that server, so I thought all requests from the client would be mapped to that user with these settings, but it doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: wait, why the obsolete NFS3 then?

Comment: I find the configuration of NFS3 more intuitive and don't really need the additional features of NFS4 from my understanding of what it offers. AFAIK nfs3 is still much more widely used than 4. However, perhaps I'll try setting it up with nfs4 instead and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out for the anonuid and gid settings to have an effect you also need to have the `all_squash` setting active, I initially thought that having those fields added would cause mid redirection to occur automatically. After updating that I'm able to `ls` the Share directory while logged in as the plex user.